# After editing a question, what should I do if I understand that sentence is too broad or something?

Tags: discussion, editing, flagging

I usually edit questions that are not very well-formatted. In fact, before reading such a question, I instantly start to edit it. In other words, I read and edit the questions simultaneously. Recently, I even jumped to answer to a possibly too-broad [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104183/forests-and-farmland-are-removed-because-of-urbanisation). As you can see on that question, one can suggest a dozen words.

However, then I decided to delete my answer and flag the question as "too-broad". I hesitated to do that because the border line between too-broad and not-too-broad is not very obvious to me.

That motivated me to ask a question here. I mean isn't it really awkward to flag a question that you edited yourself?!

Comment: I don't  see a problem with voting to close a question you have edited. Just because you've improved some aspect of a question doesn't mean there is no more work to do. I think editing is a good way to help askers learn how to improve their questions,  even if ultimately they don't edit their question to bring it on-topic.